# Best way to change a color

Tags: magento2, theme, luma-theme, extend

I have created a new theme which is inheriting from Luma.

Let's say I want to change the .page-header color, what is the best approach to do this?

Should I use a _extend.less file? Or should I copy a Luma .less file to my theme?

Thanks in advance,
Klevis

Answer (score 2):

> **Simplest way to extend parent styles**
>  To extend the parent theme’s
>   styles in your theme:
>
> In your theme directory, create a web/css/source sub-directory. Create
>   a _extend.less file there. The path to it looks like following:

```
<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

> Add your LESS code in this file. Extending
>   a theme using _extend.less is the simplest option when you are happy
>   with everything the parent theme has, but want to add more styles.
>
> **Simplest way to override parent styles** 
> To override parent styles (that
>   is, override default Magento UI library variables):
>
> In your theme directory, create a web/css/source sub-directory. Create
>   a _theme.less file here. The path to it then looks like following:

```
<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_theme.less
```

> It is important to remember that your
>   _theme.less overrides the parent _theme.less. Copy all variables you need from the parent _theme.less, including those which will not be
>   changed. For example if your theme inherits from Blank, the
>   _theme.less you should copy from is located at /web/css/source/_theme.less Make the
>   necessary changes.

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html

P.S. in your case you want to override

Comment: That's what I was thinking and it makes perfect sense. What I don't understand is this part http://prntscr.com/ii6w9n . I am overriding is the Luma theme. Why is there a /theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme and a /theme-frontend-luma/web folder?

Comment: But if you take a look inside `Magento_theme` doesnt even contain `_theme.less` file that you need @KlevisMiho

Comment: I want to change .page-header color, which is in /theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less . What approach should I take?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in this. This is not what your initial question was.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many customisations you are making, if you are only making a few small customisations such as changing color then I think it's better to use `_extend.less`.

If you're making larger customisations such as re-building/re-styling an element, or you need to change say 25% of the styling I recommend copying the file into your theme and overwriting.

I say this as using extend will add your styles on top of the parent theme styles, this isn't great for performance as your loading CSS that is not being used. For small amounts of CSS it's negligible, but if you're using extend to write a lot of CSS you could be unnecessary loading 100s of KBs of CSS.